# How to update a column with different value using simple Join statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables and i am using a simple join condition between them.

I need to find the common values and updated the **String(Success)** into the column.

input_table1:

```
ID   ||  Name   ||  output
1    ||  ABS    ||   Null
2    ||  ADF    ||   NULL
3    ||  AQS    ||   Null
4    ||  ATF    ||   NULL
5    ||  APS    ||   Null
6    ||  AMF    ||   NULL
```

Input_table2:

```
ID   ||  Name   
1    ||  ABS    
2    ||  ADF   
6    ||  AMF
```

Output_table:This is the output I need.

```
ID   ||  Name   ||  output
1    ||  ABS    ||   Success
2    ||  ADF    ||   Success
3    ||  AQS    ||   Null
4    ||  ATF    ||   NULL
5    ||  APS    ||   Null
6    ||  AMF    ||   Success.
```

This is the query i am using and this is the error is am receiving
**An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Then'.**

```
update .[dbo].[InputTable1] 
set Output= 
case when (
select INT.ID
from [dbo].[input_table1] INT
join [dbo].[input_table2] SHB
on INT.ID=SHB.ID
) Then 'Success' Else Null End
```

Comment: Good question,also try creating sample DML,DDL like below going forward..`create table #t1
(
id int,
namee char(4),
outp char(4)
)

insert into #t1
select 1    ,  'ABS'    ,   Null  union all
select 2    ,  'ADF'    ,   NULL union all`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your query should simply  be

```
update INT
set Output= 'Success'
FROM
[dbo].[input_table1] INT
join [dbo].[input_table2] SHB
on INT.ID=SHB.ID
```

<kbd>**[See working demo](http://rextester.com/RXWB84450)**</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

`...CASE WHEN <condition> = <value> THEN....`

You are missing `<value>` I suspect you need `IS NOT NULL` after your query.

That said, it is not efficient. DhruvJoshi is better

Answer (score 1):

I would use `EXISTS` and `FROM` behind `UPDATE` for that

```
UPDATE it
SET Output = (CASE WHEN exists(
       SELECT 1
       FROM [dbo].[input_table2] SHB
       WHERE it.ID=SHB.ID) 
    THEN 'Success' ELSE Null END)
FROM [dbo].[InputTable1] it
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just try this :

```
UPDATE
    InputTable1
SET
    Output='Success'
FROM
    InputTable1
    JOIN InputTable2 ON
        InputTable1.ID=InputTable2.ID
```

Only joined rows will be updated